# OpenCV color detection in yellow

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, colors

This is a program from OpenCV ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java sample, and I tried to modify it so that it would detect yellow objects when the screen is touched, but it always detects black object only even though I specified the color Scalar to be yellow. I have put comments of "NOTICE" in the places where I think would be relevant.

```
 package com.example.road_guiding;

import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;



public class ColorBlobDetectionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener, CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
//  private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
    private Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR;
    private Scalar mBlobColorHsv;
    private Scalar mBlobColorRgba;

    //NOTICE
    private Scalar temp;    

    private ColorBlobDetector mDetector;
    private boolean mIsColorSelected = false;
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        public void onManagerConnected(int paramAnonymousInt) {
            switch (paramAnonymousInt) {
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(paramAnonymousInt);
//              Log.i("OCVSample::Activity", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                ColorBlobDetectionActivity.this.mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                ColorBlobDetectionActivity.this.mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(ColorBlobDetectionActivity.this);

                return;
            }

        }
    };
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private Mat mRgba;
//  private Size SPECTRUM_SIZE;
//  private Mat mSpectrum;

    public ColorBlobDetectionActivity() {
        Log.i("OCVSample::Activity", "Instantiated new " + getClass());
    }

    private Scalar converScalarHsv2Rgba(Scalar paramScalar) {
        Mat localMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, paramScalar), localMat, 71, 4);
        return new Scalar(localMat.get(0, 0));
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame( CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame paramCvCameraViewFrame) {
        this.mRgba = paramCvCameraViewFrame.rgba(); // mRbga = input frame with color

        if (this.mIsColorSelected) {
            this.mDetector.process(this.mRgba);

            //contour info is ready in detector
            List colorContour = this.mDetector.getContours();
//          Log.e("OCVSample::Activity", "Contours count: " + localList.size());
            Imgproc.drawContours(this.mRgba, colorContour, -1, this.CONTOUR_COLOR); //draw contour around detected area     

            this.mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68).setTo(this.mBlobColorRgba);

//          Producing spectrum
//          Mat localMat = this.mRgba.submat(4, 4 + this.mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + this.mSpectrum.cols());
//          this.mSpectrum.copyTo(localMat);
        }
        return this.mRgba;
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        this.mRgba = new Mat(paramInt2, paramInt1, CvType.CV_8UC4); //width - - the width of the frames that will be delivered
        this.mDetector = new ColorBlobDetector();
        this.mBlobColorRgba = new Scalar(255.0);
        this.mBlobColorHsv = new Scalar(255.0);
        this.CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0); //Specfiy the color of contour

        //NOTICE
        this.temp = new Scalar (237.0, 169.0, 50.0, 255.0); 

        //yellow to be used:
//      this.mBlobColorRgba.val[0] = 237;
//      this.mBlobColorRgba.val[1] = 169;   
//      this.mBlobColorRgba.val[2] = 50;
//      this.mBlobColorRgba.val[3] = 255;   


//      this.mSpectrum = new Mat();
//      this.SPECTRUM_SIZE = new Size(200.0, 64.0);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
//      Log.i("OCVSample::Activity", "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
//      requestWindowFeature(1); // do not show app title
//      getWindow().addFlags(128);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_blob_detection);
        this.mOpenCvCameraView = ((CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView));
        this.mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent)
      {
        int cameraViewWidth = this.mRgba.cols(); //  cameraViewWidth = i
        int cameraViewHeight = this.mRgba.rows(); // cameraViewHeight = j
        int xOffset = (this.mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cameraViewWidth) / 2;
        int yOffset = (this.mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() - cameraViewHeight) / 2;
        int touchX = (int)paramMotionEvent.getX() - xOffset;
        int touchY = (int)paramMotionEvent.getY() - yOffset;

        //      Log.i("OCVSample::Activity", "Touch image coordinates: (" + n = touchX + ", " + i1=touchY + ")");
        if ((touchX < 0) || (touchY < 0) || (touchX > cameraViewWidth) || (touchY > cameraViewHeight)) {
          return false;
        }

        Rect touchedRect = new Rect();
        if (touchX > 4) {
          touchedRect.x = touchX - 4;
          touchedRect.y = touchY - 4;
          touchedRect.width = touchX + 4 - touchedRect.x;
        }

        for (int i5 = touchY + 4 - touchedRect.y;; i5 = cameraViewHeight - touchedRect.y) {
            touchedRect.height = i5;

//          Mat touchedRegionRgba = this.mRgba.submat(touchedRect);
            Mat touchedRegionRgba = new Mat();

            //NOTICE
            Imgproc.cvtColor(new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, temp), touchedRegionRgba, 71, 0);

            Mat touchedRegionHsv = new Mat();

            Imgproc.cvtColor(touchedRegionRgba, touchedRegionHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL); //67
            this.mBlobColorHsv = Core.sumElems(touchedRegionHsv); //calculate average color of touched region
            int pixelCount = touchedRect.width * touchedRect.height;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.mBlobColorHsv.val.length; i++) {
                double[] arrayOfDouble = this.mBlobColorHsv.val;
                arrayOfDouble[i] /= pixelCount;
          }
            touchedRegionRgba.release();
            touchedRegionHsv.release();

        break;
        }

        this.mBlobColorRgba = converScalarHsv2Rgba(this.mBlobColorHsv);

//      Log.i("OCVSample::Activity", "Touched rgba color: (" + this.mBlobColorRgba.val[0] + ", " + this.mBlobColorRgba.val[1] + ", " + this.mBlobColorRgba.val[2] + ", " + this.mBlobColorRgba.val[3] + ")");

        this.mDetector.setHsvColor(this.mBlobColorHsv);

//      Imgproc.resize(this.mDetector.getSpectrum(), this.mSpectrum, this.SPECTRUM_SIZE);
        this.mIsColorSelected = true;
        return false;
      }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (this.mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
            this.mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (this.mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
            this.mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync("2.4.3", this, this.mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        this.mRgba.release();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i don't know Java but i can suggest the general logic to detect "Yellow" color. You should convert the `RGB` image into `YUV` image and then **equalize the Y-channel**. As Y-channel is for luminance, so you reduce the effects of illumination changes by doing so.

-Then convert back your image to `RGB` from `YUV`
-Convert the image to `HSV` now.
-Now try to calculate only those pixels which possibly represent "Yellow" color. For that, use the following conditions:

1. The pixel should have `S>0` (or some other value near to 0) to eliminate the white pixels which create problem in the caculation.
2. The pixel should have `V>0` to remove the "Black pixels" which have V=0
3. If the `H> 22 && H<37` then increase the `yellowPixelCount` by 1.

-So, by following the above mentioned procedure, you can count the "yellow" pixels in the image. And, if the count is greater than the threshold then you can predict that it is "yellow" color.

PS: Don't forget to count the total number of pixel which fullfill the criteria `1` & `2` so that you can use that value to find the percentage of yellow component to predict whether the image has yellow color or not.

```
if (condition 1 & 2 satisfied)
{
    totalPixelCount++;
    if(condition 3 satisfied)
    {
        yellowPixelCount
    }
}

% of yellow componet = yellowPixelCount/totalPixelCount*100
```

Comment: Thanks skm! I will try out your approach, thank you so much for giving the advice!